# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{z^{n}}{\ln(n)}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the R.O.C. of the following power series:

$$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{z^{n}}{\ln(n)}\qquad?$$ Here is my attempt:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac {z^{n+1}\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)z^{n}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{z\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right|=z$$ so the R.O.C. = $\frac {1}{z}$. Is this right?

Comment: Well, here's a first check: the radius of convergence of a power series is a number (or possibly $+\infty$), right?  Is $\frac{1}{z}$ a number?

Comment: Pete: Actually, $1/z$ may well be a number... Which brings us back to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96420/6179), I believe. :-)

Comment: Unless I messed up the ratio test, the way I learned it is that the radius of convergence = $\frac{1}{L}$ where L is the limit obtained from the ratio test.

Comment: @Emir: That rule you cite is not quite correct. How does it make any sense that the range of possible $z$ values actually *depends* on the variable $z$? (Answer: It doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: The right formula is $1/L=\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n|$. In your case $a_n=\log(n)$.

Comment: @Emir:  Can you find the radius of converge for $\sum_n z^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem):

$$\frac{1}R=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right|^\frac{1}{n} = 1$$

Then $R=1$.

EDIT: Alternatively, the same result can be obtained using the (less general) ratio test, since:
$$\frac{1}R=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\right| = 1$$

Comment: Well, this is certainly correct, but the OP asked about the correctness of *his* argument.  So this is not a maximally helpful answer.  (And do you really think that someone who thinks a radius of convergence might be $\frac{1}{z}$ knows about the limit superior?  To me it seems unlikely.)